# Refactoring legacy C code (tightly coupled with extensive use of globals) into shared libraries

Tags: c, refactoring, global-variables, shared-libraries

I am working on a legacy system written in C. I am refactoring the code from a few **massive** modules into several smaller, logically independent shared libraries.

The problem is that the existing code make such partitioning difficult, as the large modules try to do too much. Other additional challenges are that:

- The existing code is very tightly coupled:

  For example, a module that is supposed to implement a collection structure (effectively a dynamic array) also has routines which retrieve data (to populate the structure) from file, from a database, reading cached data etc.
- The code makes extensive use of global variables, and I am not how (if?) that will work when I partition the code into separate shared libraries.

An existing header looks something like this:

```
/* DYN_ARRAY header */
DYN_ARRAY* DYN_ARRAY_Alloc(); 
void       DYN_ARRAY_Free(DYN_ARRAY *ptr); 
int        DYN_ARRAY_LoadFile(DYN_ARRAY *ptr, cont char* filename, FILE_STRUCT_INFO *info);

/* obvious dependency on database functionality */
int        DYN_ARRAY_LoadQueryResults(DYN_ARRAY *ptr, const char* sql);

/* This innocuous looking function calls a function which introduces
   a dependencies on another logically separate module
```

*/
    int        DYN_ARRAY_GetIdKeyValue(const DYN_ARRAY *ptr, const int key_id);

I am thinking of diving the existing DYN_ARRAY module into three shared libraries as follows:

1. dyn_array_core   (depends: none)
2. dyn_array_db     (depends: dyn_array_core, db_utils ...)
3. dyn_array_misc   (depends: dyn_array_core, misc_utils ...)

My questions are:

1. Is this a sensible approach (or is there a better way to partition the code?)
2. Will the partitioned code work as before (giving the fact that the code uses global variables - i.e. will each dll have its own copy of a global var? [if yes, then obviously thats not what I want] - in which case how do I refactor the code to work as before?)

Comment: Do you have any tests?

Comment: If you want to make changes that accomplish something useful, moving code into separate shared objects is not going to do much. A better effort, in my opinion, is to first rewrite the code to eliminate as many of those globals as you can -- build one or more structures to hold your context instead, and modify function signatures to include a context pointer. Once you're there, separation of code into better delineated modules (and perhaps multiple shared libraries) will give you a more useful output.

Comment: @mah: I did think of using the approach you suggest (see my previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752282/making-existing-ansi-c-code-threadsafe-and-re-entrant)), but was overwhelmed with the amount of work involved with that approach. Still, could you please elaborate some more (in an answer perhaps), how I may wrap up the globals in a context structure like you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli sure, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make changes that accomplish something useful, moving code into separate shared objects is not going to do much. A better effort, in my opinion, is to first rewrite the code to eliminate as many of those globals as you can -- build one or more structures to hold your context instead, and modify function signatures to include a context pointer. Once you're there, separation of code into better delineated modules (and perhaps multiple shared libraries) will give you a more useful output.

To get started with this, you might want to make a new header whose intent will be to define the structure that former globals get relocated to. First note that we want to do all of this refactoring *without moving code into shared libraries* -- only do that after you've verified that the initial refactoring was successful. (I.e., don't introduce more potential failure points than are necessary at one time.)

```
#ifndef _FORMER_GLOBALS_H_
#define _FORMER_GLOBALS_H_

typedef struct GlobalContext {
} GlobalContext;

GlobalContext *CreateGlobalContext(); // a convenience function

#endif /* _FORMER_GLOBALS_H_ */
```

Next step is to move all of the globals you want to eliminate into this structure. If you know where all the globals are defined then the task is easy... just cut them out of their source location, *take note of any non-zero initial values*, and move the variable definitions into the structure (without initializations). If the current location of your globals is not well defined (they're sprinkled all over the place) then this step is more difficult but your compiler tools may be able to help you find the globals in current code.

Next consider the `CreateGlobalContext()` function. This function is going to allocate a context structure and initialize it; if you have no non-zero initializations then you could eliminate the function completely.

```
GlobalContext *CreateGlobalContext()
{
    GlobalContext *context = malloc(sizeof(*context));
    memset(context, 0, sizeof(*context)); // initialize it to all zeros

    // if needed, initialize individual non-zero elements
    // context->some_non_zero = 1;

    return context;
}
```

Now that you have no more globals (in the code modules you plan to move), and a way to create storage for them with their proper initialization, you've currently got a bunch of code that won't compile - you should have unresolved references or unknown identifiers for all of the former globals.

Any function that accessed globals that have been moved should have a new parameter added to it. So for example, consider this kind of change:

```
extern int global_a;
void FunctionToBeMoved(int a)
{
    global_a = a;
}

// the above old function becomes:
void FunctionToBeMoved(GlobalContext *context, int a)
{
    context->global_a = a;
}
```

Once these conversions are done, you'll need to modify how each of the changed functions gets called -- they'll need to simply pass along the context they're now receiving (or now need to receive if you left it out due to lack of direct global usage).

This is not a small amount of work -- but converting poorly written code into something that is readable / maintainable generally is large.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That goes someway toward answering the question about globals. I have 2 questions: **First:**, if `createGlobalContext` is defined in **moduleA**, and it is used in **moduleC** and **moduleD** (for example), with each module being a separate compilation unit (or even shared library), will there not be multiple copies of the globals?. **Second question** is to do with calling decoupling the modules. Can I just provide function prototypes for a module (so it compiles), and leave the references to be resolved at run time (the complete app will link to all the shared libs).

Comment: A1: yes; you want to only call `createGlobalContext()` once... that caller has the responsibility to propagate the context to any other code that needs it. A2: yes, this is how it works for a static linkage of your shared object. It's possible to do a dynamic linkage also (declaring your own function pointers instead, locating them manually at run time) -- dynamic linkage is more appropriate for shared objects as an optional plugin. Static seems to fit your need more correctly.